# lambda function triggers only for a upload of filename pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Let's say I upload folder/key.jpg to a S3 bucket. How would I trigger a lambda function only when a file contains jpg at the end of File Name, is uploaded?

Is this possible or do I need to check the filename in the function and early-out it doesn't match what I'm looking for?

The reason I ask is that a lot of stuff will be uploaded to the bucket, and it seems inefficient (and costly) for the function to trigger every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [S3 Event notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html).

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to trigger lambda only on jpg image is uploaded in your s3 folder, follow https://n2ws.com/blog/aws-automation/lambda-function-s3-event-triggers. Just add jpg as suffix and foldername as prefix in event section of s3.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Suffix filter. As per this [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/amazon-s3-adds-prefix-and-suffix-filters-for-lambda-function-triggering/)